# When is it useful to add [tag: ... ] formatting to words in a tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, edits, markdown, tag-wiki

I've seen a bunch of users which has been making multiple edits to tag wikis just to add links to tags, sometimes even when they do not exist. For example, some of the edits change something like this:

> There should only be one LeadingMarginSpan2 per paragraph.

to this:

> There should only be one [leadingmarginspan2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leadingmarginspan2) per paragraph.

While I don't think this particular change is very useful, I've seen this being used in a beneficial manner in large tag wikis (e.g. [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)), where they reference other related concepts or technologies which themselves have useful tag wikis.

So, when does adding these sorts of things become useful, and are there cases where adding tag references end up being more annoying than beneficial?

Comment: I only use the tag syntax when referring to a tag, not the concept or technology represented by the tag.